# Standalone Sonar runner from Jenkins missing mvn.bat and pom.xml

Tags: .net, maven, sonarqube

I've configured Sonar to run at the end of my Jenkins build for a C# project. The log shows that Sonar made it all the way through the analysis, but the build is failing on some kind of cleanup step. It's also looking for pom.xml, which doesn't exist. Any idea why mvn.bat is trying to run in the standalone version of Sonar and how to turn this off/get it to run successfully? Many thanks.

```
16:02:28.256 INFO  .b.p.UpdateStatusJob - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonarserver:9000
16:02:28.256 INFO  b.p.PostJobsExecutor - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
16:02:28.288 INFO  b.p.PostJobsExecutor - Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
16:02:28.303 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2012-07-27 and 2012-08-23
16:02:28.303 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2011-08-26 and 2012-07-27
16:02:28.303 INFO  .p.d.p.KeepOneFilter - -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2007-08-31 and 2011-08-26
16:02:28.303 INFO  .d.p.DeleteAllFilter - -> Delete data prior to: 2007-08-31
16:02:28.303 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - -> Clean MyProject:MyProjectDevelopment [id=1]
16:02:28.319 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - <- Clean snapshot 3727
16:02:29.647 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - -> Clean MyProject.Library [id=2]
16:02:29.663 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - -> Clean MyProject.Web [id=3]
16:02:29.663 INFO  o.s.c.purge.PurgeDao - -> Clean MyProjectOmnitureDownloader [id=4]
Total time: 1:04.065s
Final Memory: 4M/26M
[workspace] $ mvn.bat -f "H:\jobs\MyProject\workspace\pom.xml" -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver "-Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://sonarserver:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true" ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarserver:9000 -Dsonar.language=cs
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn.bat" (in directory "H:\jobs\MyProject\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:709)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
    at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:263)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarMaven.executeMaven(SonarMaven.java:138)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.executeSonar(SonarPublisher.java:300)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.perform(SonarPublisher.java:261)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:685)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:632)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1463)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Sonar' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: me@myproject.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Sonar Jenkins plugin and [enabled it on your build](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Activate+Sonar+on+Jenkins+job)?

The Jenkins plugin uses Maven to launch Sonar analysis. It runs at the end of your job so might look like a clean-up step.